# AdMob error - across 3 apps

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

I created a new app today and put it on Google Play after testing on the emulator and 2 devices I own. A friend then downloaded it to give it a look-see and said that he did not see any ad (using AdMob). This baffled me 'cos I had seen the test ad on my development device **and** in the emulator.

I thought I had done everything I needed to do correctly with the new app, but I checked two older apps that I'd created previously which also used AdMob, to satisfy myself.

I ran these two apps from within Android Studio on my Motorola Xoom connected via USB. I seem to be **now** getting errors in LogCat like this across all 3 apps...

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Two of these apps are apps that I've not touched for some time, I just re-opened them in Android Studio today to see if they could help me understand why the new app wasn't working as I'd expected. I can confirm 100% that ads have been working in them prior to this.

I **do** see the test AdMob ad on my development devices. I also see:

```
I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
```

Eventually in LogCat.

Can anyone help me understand this better? I looked at another SO question and it seemed to be related to location services, but none of my apps make use of location.

I checked on the AdMob dashboard, and it is also clearly showing that the new app has a number of impressions **today**, which is even more confusing.

I am using Android Studio 0.4.6.

I am using Google Play Services com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42.

I have performed a Clean, Rebuild on these projects and I have stopped and restarted Android Studio. Any input appreciated so I can understand what's truly going on here.

Comment: Are you accessing Admob via Google Play services or the Admob SDK?

Comment: Hi - my `build.gradle` has compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'`, my Activity imports `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;` and `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;` and my XML view is defined as `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`... so I'd say Google Play Services... I now have 2 users (friends) telling me different things for the same app - one saying that he sees space for the ad reserved but no ad, one has sent me a screenshot showing the ad is working. Could this be an issue outside my immediate area of responsibility as the Developer, i.e. poss. at the ad server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to be concerned about.

Current version of Google Play Services seems to have a benign bug where this message sometimes gets displayed:

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

But it doesn't stop your app from working or ads being displayed.

If there are no ads available for a certain area/device then occasionally an ad won't get displayed. But that is perfectly normal. It's why you should use mediation to make sure you always have ad fill.

Comment: Thank you for this reassurance. The person who is not seeing ads (first on my latest app, but *now* on all 3 of my apps that he has installed) is located in Ireland, I wonder if that has any bearing. I don't yet know about mediation, so maybe this is something extra that I need to look into.